# Getting started 5.13 RecordNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The blog tutorial in Getting started says to use the following code for destroying a record:

```
def destroy
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @article.destroy

  redirect_to articles_path
end
```

But it returns the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ArticlesController#destroy
Couldn't find Article with 'id'=15
```

Can someone please explain why this is? Outcommenting the destroy call just redirects to the view page of that record. Is the destroy method called twice? How can it complain it doesn't exist when it obviously does? And why does it redirect to the view page of the record it should be deleting?

Changing the redirect to:

```
redirect_to :root if @article.destroy
```

Solves the problem. Although I cannot redirect to `'index'`. Why is that?

Comment: it seems 2 times call. open your browser console and see Network tab after clicking on destroy link......

Comment: @ArupRakshit: How would I see that in the network tab? It only shows the last call, and it would not show if it was called twice internally in one call.

Comment: If 2 DELETE http request happened,,, you will see it in network tab...

Comment: All I have is one 404 request, with request method POST.

Comment: destroy should be delete http  verb